# Fastest way to compare one string of two lengths

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, comparison, string-comparison

I'm looking for the fastest way to compare if a string has one of two lengths. This string must be either one letter longer or shorter, and I feel that the if statement below might not be the fastest and I don't see much of an improvement in time with it, or without it.

---

I'm comparing between two string, if `my_word` length is more than 1 character less or more than `compare_word` then I shall continue my loop.

```
if (len(compare_word) > (len(my_word)+1)) and (len(compare_word) < (len(my_word)-1)): 
    continue
```

Comment: What about using `abs` of the difference?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the condition in the question is incorrect. `len(compare_word)` will never be simultaneously greater than **and** less than `len(my_word)`.

Comment: @Robᵩ You are right `and` is forcing more checks that I need, by changing it to `or, it has dramatically increased my time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- you do not need to call [`len`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) twice,
- you can utilize [`abs`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs)

Example:

```
s = "Hello"
t = "Worl"

if abs(len(s) - len(t)) > 1:
    print("string lengths differ by more than 1")
```

---

Update: With ipython's [`timeit`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.magics.execution.html?highlight=timeit#IPython.core.magics.execution.ExecutionMagics.timeit) there are almost no speed gain, however:

```
In [10]: s = str(range(100000))

In [11]: t = str(range(100001))

In [12]: %timeit len(s) > len(t) + 1 and len(s) < len(t) - 1
10000000 loops, best of 3: 106 ns per loop

In [13]: %timeit abs(len(s) - len(t)) > 1
10000000 loops, best of 3: 115 ns per loop

In [14]: %timeit 1 >= len(s) - len(t) >= -1
10000000 loops, best of 3: 113 ns per loop
```

Here's another run with shorter strings, but about the same result: https://gist.github.com/miku/6904419.

Nevertheless, in the [context](http://pastebin.com/UNZ2z2ae) of OPs code, `abs(len(s) - len(t)) > 1` really is faster.

Comment: remarkable how much faster this is. Shaved 1.5 seconds off my search.

Comment: @czl, really? I posted some benchmarks and they come out approximately the same.

Comment: Yes, I take the time at the start of my loop and subtract it by the end time, when I output a list. I'm comparing a string from a set with my own string. For "the fastest" `if 1 >= len(w) - len(word) >= -1: continue` averages `1.5 seconds`. Then for my solution it's `1.65 seconds`. After using `abs(len(s1) - len(s2) >1` the time drops down to `0.13` seconds.

Comment: Interesting, would you mind pasting your code (modulo any confidential things) in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or a [paste](http://pastebin.com/)? I'm just curious about the context which yields such differences.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UNZ2z2ae words.txt is the generic linux dictionary, by changing my condition to 'or' it also increaed perfromance

Comment: @czl, thanks, that's great! It obviously works, but the *why* still escapes me.

Comment: @czl, ah, by looking at the bytecode, if get a bit more obvious, why it's faster - https://gist.github.com/miku/6904419#file-gistfile1-txt

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the fastest way is

```
if 1 >= len(s) - len(t) >= -1:
    print("string lengths differ by more than 1")
```

Indeed:

```
>>> %timeit abs(a) <= 1
1000000 loops, best of 3: 283 ns per loop
>>> %timeit  1 >= a >= -1
10000000 loops, best of 3: 198 ns per loop
```

Comment: +1, saves the `abs` call. However, all three code snippets so far seem to come out [very similar](https://gist.github.com/miku/6904419) - can it be?